# CSS - different approaches of styling a class

Tags: html, css

Reading the following CSS code I was wondering, what is the difference between a) and b)? Is the first declaration a good way of styling?

a)

```
.round_box.icon{

  ....
}
```

b)

```
.round_box .icon{

  ....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With A : You select all the elements with the 2 classes (at the same time)

With B : You select all the elements with class icon inside all the elements with class round_box