# Qualified CSS selectors, what is more efficient?

Tags: html, css

I wonder which of the following CSS declaration is more efficient and why?

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/37BWL/)

HTML

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div> hallo </div>    
</div>
```

CSS
Version 1:

```css
.wrap div{

   color: red;
}
```

CSS Version 2:

```css
div.wrap{

  color: red;
 }
```

Comment: They mean completely different things, so efficiency is irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - different approaches of styling a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173203/css-different-approaches-of-styling-a-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
div .wrap{
   color: red;
}
```

Will typically be faster, assuming there are no levels of prior nesting not referred to and the level of relative uniqueness of `.wrap` is higher than that for `div`, as browsers interpret and filter selectors **right-to-left**, typically the level of selector efficiency goes*:

1. ID, e.g. #header
2. Class, e.g. .promo
3. Type, e.g. div
4. Adjacent sibling, e.g. h2 + p
5. Child, e.g. li > ul
6. Descendant, e.g. ul a
7. Universal, i.e. *
8. Attribute, e.g. [type="text"]
9. Pseudo-classes/-elements, e.g. a:hover

*[Source](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/)

You may want to also have a read of [this great article at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS) ([and this one as an update to that](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/css-selector-performance-has-changed-for-the-better/))

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how many divs you have and how many instances of the `.wrap` class you have created.

If there are 10 `divs` and 100 `.wrap` instances then go with version 2, as there are fewer `div` to test than `.wrap`.

How ever I suppose the lookup may be implementation dependent.